# Safety and getting around in Nuevo Laredo Mexico

Tags: mexico

What is the safety and taxi situation in Nuevo Laredo Mexico? I did a search for Uber and it looks like there is no uber service at all in that city. I usually associate that with a city that is less than safe. Am I wrong on that? Is it possible to hail taxis on the street there?

Comment: Until recently, Canberra Australia didn't have uber.  Until recently it wasn't in London (banned).  I think your association might have some flaws...

Answer (score 3):

Of course your experience may vary, but Tamaulipas is among the 5 Mexican states (out of 31) that are listed as 'Do Not Travel' in the [US Department of State Mexico Travel Advisory](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/traveladvisories/traveladvisories/mexico-travel-advisory.html) for August 22, 2018:

> Tamaulipas state – Level 4: Do Not Travel
>
> Do not travel due to crime. Violent crime, such as murder, armed robbery, carjacking, kidnapping, extortion, and sexual assault, is common. Gang activity, including gun battles, is widespread. Armed criminal groups target public and private passenger buses traveling through Tamaulipas, often taking passengers hostage and demanding ransom payments. Local law enforcement has limited capability to respond to violence in many parts of the state.